# diffing line coverage in code view in sonarqube5 vs earlier version of sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

Way back in Sonarqube 3 there was a feature in the code page to diff changes. For example you could view line coverage on only lines of code which have changed (only changed lines would be displayed in the code view).

I've recently jumped an entire version to Sonarqube 5 and am wondering where this feature is accessed from?  If it has been removed, which sonarqube version did that happen at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that is "new" (added or modified) in the leak period is marked in the margin of the code viewer with a vertical blue line.

Comment: Thanks G. Ann.  In my case I'm managing a number of quite legacy Java projects with some very large class files (3000+ lines not unheard of).

It's important to be able to condense the code page information to make it clearer which code is not tested, and where code coverage therefore needs to improve.